# filtrar datos datagriddview, data table C#

Tags: c#, datatables, datagrid, directorioactivo

Es posible filtrar datos de un datagridview sin antes haber cargado la data? Es que tengo un data gridview que cargo con información de active directory la cuál asigno a un datatable y posteriormente este datatable lo asigno como datasource al gridview y carga perfectamente, ahora lo que quiero hacer es un filtro de busqueda que conforme se vaya digitando en un textbox una palabra se vayan mostrando los resultados coincidentes y conseguí hacer uno que funciona pero **NO funciona a menos que se haya cargado primero la data en el gridview** lo que yo quiero es que al abrir la aplicación se muestre un gridview en blanco sin columnas ni nada pero cuando se digite la búsqueda aparezcan los valores de la misma.

No sé si esto sea posible

Codigo que uso para cargar el datagrid con la info de active directory

```
private void loadGrid()
    {

        DirectoryEntry direntry = new DirectoryEntry();
        direntry.Path = "LDAP://";
        DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(direntry);

        dirSearcher.Filter = "(objectClass=User)";


        resultsTable.Columns.Add("Nombre",typeof(string));
        resultsTable.Columns.Add("Apellido", typeof(string));
        resultsTable.Columns.Add("Puesto", typeof(string));
        resultsTable.Columns.Add("# Empleado", typeof(string));
        resultsTable.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));

        int row = 0;

        foreach (SearchResult sr in dirSearcher.FindAll())
        {
resultsTable.Rows.Add(sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value);
                resultsTable.Rows[row]["Apellido"] = sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sn"].Value;
                resultsTable.Rows[row]["Puesto"] = sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["title"].Value;
                resultsTable.Rows[row]["# Empleado"] = sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["employeeNumber"].Value;
                resultsTable.Rows[row]["Username"] = sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sAMAccountname"].Value;


            row++;
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = resultsTable;
    }
```

Codigo usado para filtrar la información (pero solo el datagrid ya está cargado)

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resultsTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"nombre LIKE '{textBox1.Text}%'";
        }
```

Lo que se quiere es que al abrir el form el datagrid aparezca asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y que al ir digitando la busqueda en el texbox se vayan viendo los resultados

Comment: Podrías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el código como un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Davlio listo, ahi añadí el código que uso para meter los valores de active en el datagrid y el que uso para filtrar

Comment: ¿Por qué no se debe mostrar la información del gridview antes de filtrarla? Podrías intentar jugar con el control, colocarlo a falso en su propiedad visible, y en tu método textBox1_TextChanged, luego del filtro colocar su propiedad visible a verdadero. Si detectas que el textbox se queda en blanco, volver a colocar la propiedad visible como falsa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones. Una es que al cargar el formulario, no establezcas el `DataSource` hasta que no se haya tecleado algo, y en el evento `TextChanged` compruebes y si está vacío el textbox, pongas el `DataSource`a null. Pero lo que yo haría sería jugar con el filtro, poniendo un filtro que no pueda darse,algo como `nombre=asdfg`.

En el `loadGrid`:

```
...
dataGridView1.DataSource = resultsTable;
resultsTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "nombre=asdfg";
```

Y luego en el `TextChanged`:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length==0)
     {
         resultsTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "nombre=asdfg";
     }
     else
     {
         resultsTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"nombre LIKE '{textBox1.Text}%'";
     }
}
```

Es una solución sencilla que creo que dará los resultados que esperas.